# Как перевести такой javascript в json?

Tags: php, javascript, массивы, json

Имею такой код на javascript

```
RegionIds = [637640, 653240], countryIds = [621540, 803730], stamps = {
    metro: "f4f9c25",
    district: "2989c65",
    road: "411c27f",
    location: "cf2bf98",
    directions: "e1e21ec"
}
```

Как можно преобразовать это в json для дальнейшего использования в php?

Comment: Вы уверены, что это корректный JS? Что за запятые такие?

Comment: @A1essandro это обычное объявление переменных без ключевого слова var.

Comment: методом ручного перевода переменных в JSON. Лучше бы сразу начинали работать с объектом типа JSON, чтобы и в js его использовать и в php

Comment: @A1essandro, запятые в js корректны, как и в си. Позволяют сделать из нескольких операторов один.

Answer (score 2):

```
var o = {}

o.RegionIds = [637640, 653240],
o.countryIds = [621540, 803730],
o.stamps = {
    metro: "f4f9c25",
    district: "2989c65",
    road: "411c27f",
    location: "cf2bf98",
    directions: "e1e21ec"
}

var data = JSON.stringify(o);
console.log(data);
```

результат:

```
{
   "RegionIds":[
      637640,
      653240
   ],
   "countryIds":[
      621540,
      803730
   ],
   "stamps":{
      "metro":"f4f9c25",
      "district":"2989c65",
      "road":"411c27f",
      "location":"cf2bf98",
      "directions":"e1e21ec"
   }
}
```

т.е. `data` содержит валидный JSON.